# jbpm 5.4 doesn't work with jdk1.5 version of websphere application server 6.1

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to integrate jbpm5.4 with websphere app server 6.1 but it seems the war's of jbpm5.4 has been compiled with jdk1.6 due to which it is not supporting was6.1.Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build jbpm from source. 
Or even better migrate to Websphere 7, since 6.1 will run out of support in 22 days.